# Adding Angular expression to php

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I'm learning angular and I've got an angular expression {{movie.title}} which outputs the movie title. If I include it in some php as

```
$movTitle = "{{movie.title}}"; 
echo $movTitle;
```

it prints the movie title. However if I send $movTitle to a function it doesn't get parsed.

```
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("$movTitle"); // doesn't get movie info
// $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("Scarface"); // gets movie info
```

Any ideas on the best way to send the movie title to the php function?

--update--

I thought this might be something simple I missed but as it appears to be a little more complex I've added the page code for a bit more context. I'm declaring the component templateUrl: 'movie.component.php' and this is that file.

```
<?php
include("/path/imdb.php"); 
?>
<div *ngIf="movie">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>    
        </div> 
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Genres: <span *ngFor="let genre of movie.genres">{{genre.name}}</span></li>    
                        <li class="list-group-item">Release Date: {{movie.release_date}}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <a *ngIf="movie.homepage" href="{{movie.homepage}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Visit Movie Website</a>

<?php
      $movTitle = "{{movie.title}}"; 
      $imdb = new Imdb();
      $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("$movTitle");
      echo '<table align=center style="color:white;font-family:verdana;font-size:15px;line-height:1.7;" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="1" border="1" width="100%" align="center">';
      foreach ($movieArray as $key=>$value){
          $value = is_array($value)?implode("<br />", $value):$value;
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<th align="left" valign="top">' .
          str_replace("_","&nbsp;",strtoupper($key)) . '</th><td>' . $value .
         '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
?>                 

                </div>  
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</div>
```

The IMDB function imports additional details about the movie. I'd like this function to execute on this page. I figure I'll need to place the php in the back, use $http to post the movie title then render the returned data (the table) on the page.

Comment: `$movTitle` as far as your PHP is concerned is only ever going to equal `"{{movie.title}}"`. I'm a little confused about how you're trying to merge the use of PHP and Angular?

Comment: I'm declaring the component templateUrl: 'movie.component.php' and in this file I want to parse the movie title

Comment: Your PHP lives on a server, and should have no knowledge of your Angular code. You use Angular to request data from the PHP server via API HTTP calls, you shouldn't really be trying to combine the 2 in the same place.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I thought when php printed out the movie title I was able to parse that. I'll look at ajax requests using the $http service as mentioned below.

Comment: @Stev As mentioned by others, Angular should have no knowledge of PHP, and you should be making **http-calls** to your backend (PHP). Your backend and frontend are **completely** separate.

Comment: Here's a really rough example, **and** notice that this is using old Angular syntax, but the idea is the same. You have your backend separately on whatever server you want to run your backend, and make http-calls from Angular to that backend: http://4dev.tech/2016/07/using-http-client-to-integrate-angular2-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a request using AngularJs to an endpoint of your PHP backend, and you would send the movie title along with this request. You can look here: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp for reference on how to do ajax requests using the $http service in Angular.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow that up

Comment: No problem. If you like the answer please accept it.

Comment: @Stev If you are using Angular, that link is the wrong place, since that is **AngularJS**. Check the official docs for Angular about http instead: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html That is, if you are using *Angular* instead of *AngularJS*

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks. It is running on the Angular framework, I thought AngularJS was what it used.

Comment: @GullDe I'm not sure this is the right answer yet. I'll add the page code to the question to give it a bit more context. Thanks